# Implement non blocking progress dialog like playstore and facebook

Tags: android-asynctask, android, android-progressbar

I am implementing custom `progressDialog` in my app where I am using `animation-list` to display a moving image but what I want to do is, embed my `progressDialog` in my activity such that it doesn't overlap on the screen and when the task is completed, view get updated whereas on back click activity finishes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create `ProgressDialog` within your activity and hide the other layout.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView style="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
            android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/lorem_ipsum"
            android:padding="16dp" />

    </ScrollView>

    <ProgressBar android:id="@+id/loading_spinner"
        style="?android:progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

</FrameLayout>
```

After fetching data from network call, hide the `ProgressBar` and show your data.